# How to kill a tcp connection in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I want to kill a connection (may be ESTABLISHED  or FIN_WAIT_1 )

windows API offer a function "SetTcpEntry"  .

What's the function similar to "SetTcpEntry"  in Linux ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [close](https://web.archive.org/web/20111230025435/http://www.cs.vu.nl:80/~jms/socket-info.html) to close the socket in code, if you're trying to kill it from the shell, find out which process is bound to the port using [netstat (1)](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?netstat++NetBSD-current) and kill that process using [kill -9](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?kill++NetBSD-current) -- hope that helps!

Comment: yeah but it will kill the process . the settcpentry function just close the connetion but do not terminate the process